# What's the best and fastest way to bring my Syrian fiance who lives and works in Poland to the United States? ( I'm a US citizen)

Tags: usa, us-citizens, greencard

I'm a US citizen (age 29), and I met my Syrian fiance (age 31) years ago when we were at school in Syria. After the war, we had to split up. He now lives and works in Poland for a large technology company, and I moved to the US because it was easier for me as a US citizen.

With Trump's travel ban in 2017, is it still possible for me to bring him to the States so we can live together? And is it better to do a fiance visa (K1) and get married here in the States, or to get married outside the States and apply for a different kind of visa?

Comment: If syria is from one of those 5 muslim countries that Trump has banned, I believe it is not possible. Two of my friends(iranian) how were married to american born citizens couldn’t do that (two failed cases). They are comming to Iran to live together 

Answer (score 2):

When you say he is "Syrian", do you mean he is a Syrian citizen? Does he have another nationality with which he can get another passport?

If he is a Syrian citizen, and he does not have access to a passport from a non-banned country, he will not be able to get an immigrant or nonimmigrant visa to the US under the current travel ban. It doesn't matter if you try to get him a fiance visa or if you marry him first and try to get him an immigrant visa; both ways are banned.

On the other hand, if he is a dual national of Syria and a non-banned country, and he is traveling on the passport of that non-banned country, the travel ban does not affect him.

Comment: He is a Syrian citizen with no other nationality. He only has a Syrian passport with a residency in Poland. Would he qualify for a waiver since he's of "national interest" since he's a senior professional in technology?

Comment: @Varda Elentári According to https://www.aila.org/File/DownloadEmbeddedFile/75354
“the applicant’s travel may be considered in the national interest if a US person or entity would suffer hardship if the applicant could not travel until after visa restrictions imposed with respect to nationals of that country are lifted.”